# Harvard style (apsr.bst) struggling with URLs with embedded &

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

Just moved to the [apsr.bst style](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/apsr.bst) in anticipation of a journal submission, and now my builds are choking on URLs with embedded ampersands. I'm getting LOTS of errors like:

```
./myfile.bbl:20: Misplaced alignment tab character &. [...&dq=civic+culture&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api}]
```

Oddly, in the .bbl, it seems that there is a sanitizing wrap -- here's the aforementioned line 20:

```
\newline\harvardurl{http://books.google.com/books?id=J93o05MH3v8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=civic+culture&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api}
```

I have a lot of citations and really don't want to sanitize them all by hand. Anyone know how to fix in the bib file?

EDIT: Full example entry in the .bbl file:

```
\harvarditem{Almond \harvardand\ Verba}{1989}{Almond:2011uw}
Almond, Gabriel~A \harvardand\ Sidney Verba. 1989.
\newblock {\em {The Civic Culture}}.
\newblock Political Attitudes and Democracy in Five Nations SAGE.
\newline\harvardurl{http://books.google.com/books?id=J93o05MH3v8C\&printsec=frontcover\&dq=civic+culture\&hl=&cd=1\&source=gbs_api}
```

Comment: Is the `url` package being loaded?

Comment: @mico I have the url package in my main document and it loads. Is there another place I need to call it?

Comment: Please post a sample bib entry that contains a URL string.

Comment: Do you load the `harvard` style file as well? (The macro `\harvardurl` is defined in `harvard.sty`.)

Comment: I've only loaded the apsr.bst and natbib -- excuse my ignorance, but how do I load more style files?

Comment: Incidentally, which document class do you use?

Comment: You should load either the `harvard` citation management package or the `natbib` citation management package, *but not both*. When working with the `apsr` bibstyle, you should actually load the `har2nat` package (which, inter alia, loads the `natbib` package)  if you want to work with the `natbib` package rather than the `harvard` package.  Why might one prefer the `natbib` package rather than the `harvard` package? There may be several reasons, but an especially good reason (for me at least) is that `natbib` has better interoperability with the `hyperref` package.

Comment: Oh, and please post the "raw" entry from the bib file, not the formatted entry from the bbl file.